# Sharing file across library project

Tags: java, android, ipc, aidl, android-service-binding

I am writing a library project which can be installed across multiple apps.
In order for the library to function it needs to download files. My goal is to download the files once and share them across other instances of my library in other apps. (I want to save the network traffic), how do I achieve this. Public external storage is not an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **share functionality** between different android applications, you should implement the **Inter-Process Communication (IPC)** between them.

Since android applications are actually sandboxed linux processes, they do not have access to each other's private data and files.

In the domain of Android development, there are two ways to implement IPC :

**[Messengers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html)** and **[AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)** ( Android Interface Definiton Language), which both make use of the bound services in application.

I recommend you to start studying the aformentioned documents to get a big picture on the subject.